# Flutter spaceEvenly/spaceBetween not working

Tags: flutter, frontend, login-page

[image: emulator snapshot]

I'm trying to create a login  page, and I want to make some space between the second text field and the login button , tried `spaceBetween` and `spaceAround` but didn't work

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
  child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
    Container( padding:EdgeInsets.all(10),
      color: Colors.blueGrey,
      child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
        Text("Login",style:TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20)),
        TextField(
          controller: name_field,
        ),
        TextField(
          controller: password_field,
        ),
        Container(color: Colors.blue,alignment: Alignment.center,padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
          child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  return SecondScreen(
                      name: name_field.text, pass: password_field.text);
                }));
              },
              child: Text("Login",style:TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
        ),
      ]),
    ),
  ]),
));
```

}
}

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no enough place in the Container for having space between any widgets since you haven't specified height for Container.

So you should either give that Container some height or Place a SizedBox between widgets you wish to have space. I'll suggest the second option for this situation.

```
Scaffold(
    body: Center(
  child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
    Container(
      //height: 300, //Use this (option 1)
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      color: Colors.blueGrey,
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text("Login",
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20)),
            TextField(
                controller: name_field,
                ),
            TextField(
                controller: password_field,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30,),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
              child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                      return SecondScreen(
                          name: name_field.text, pass: password_field.text);
                    }));
                  },
                  child:
                      Text("Login", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
            ),
          ]),
    ),
  ]),
));
```

Answer (score 1):

`mainAxisAlignment` will adjust child with main axis, but in your case, you are using 'Center' that make 'Column' minimum size, it mean **no waster space inside** `Column`.

To fix this, you can remove `Center` or fix height of `Container` like this

**Example**: remove `Center`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container( // Center and unnecessary column removed, now Container will take full screen as size, child column will have space to align
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            const Text("Login"),
            // const SizedBox(height: 70), // Or add `SizedBox` on each child
            const TextField(),
            const TextField(),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text("Login"),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Space between only works if there's space for it to distribute. There's a few things you're doing here that's not correct.

1. Remove the Column that is the child of the Center widget. It's not doing anything. That should fix your problem. Then there's additional things you can do.
2. Set the Column in the container's size to max so it can take up the full screen and not wrap its children

```dart
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
```